# Jackson: deserializing recursive object

Tags: java, json, jackson, kendo-grid

I'm trying to parse the filter parameters sent by a KendoUI grid to my web service and am having some issues convincing Jackson to parse this JSON. As far as I know, I can control the format of the parameters that Kendo sends, but I do not know how I would marshal the parameters into a better format so they remain unchangeable for now.

I intend to convert these parameters into a SQL query for an Oracle database.

## Example JSON:

```
{
    "filters":
    [
        {
            "field": "Name",
            "operator": "contains",
            "value": "John"
        },
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "Age",
                    "operator": "gt",
                    "value": 20
                },
                {
                    "field": "Age",
                    "operator": "lt",
                    "value": 85
                }
            ],
            "logic", "and"
        },
        {
            "field": "Address",
            "operator": "doesnotcontain",
            "value": "street"
        }
    ],
    "logic": "or"
}
```

## Filters. Java

```
public class Filters {
    private List<Filter> filters;
    private String logic;
    // accessors/mutators/toString
}
```

## Filter.java

```
public class Filter {
    private String field;
    private String operator;
    private String value;
    // accessors/mutators/toString
}
```

## Unit Test

```
public class KendoGridFilterTest {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonParseTest() {
        final String json = "{\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"Name\",\"operator\":\"contains\",\"value\":\"John\"},{filters: [{\"field\":\"Age\",\"operator\": \"eq\",\"value\": 85},{\"field\": \"Age\",\"operator\": \"eq\",\"value\": 85}]\"logic\", \"and\",},{\"field\": \"Address\",\"operator\": \"doesnotcontain\",\"value\": \"street\"}],\"logic\":\"or\"}";
        Filters filters = mapper.readValue(json, Filters.class);
        assertTrue(json.equals(filters.writeValueAsString(filters);
    }
}
```

## Errors

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field 
    'logic'(com.example.Filter) not market as ignorable (3 known properties 
    "value", "field", "operator")
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3bb2b8; line: 1, column 76] (through reference 
    chain: com.example.Filters["filters"]->com.example.Filter["logic"]
```

I've also tried adding `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")` to the Filters class and get the same errors.

Comment: It looks like maybe the `Filters` class should also contain a `Filters` as a member too since the outside "filters" looks like there's another "filter" object inside of it (though it's weird that the outside one has quotes and the inside one does not).

Comment: I fixed the omission of quotes. The issue that I see is that the parent and the child both have the same name, so I can't return the key "filters" unless the variable is named "filters" (or remapped using @JsonProperty(value="filters"). I think I'm getting a little confused by the recursive nature of this JSON.

Comment: You have a getter and a setter for each private field?

Comment: Yes, and I feel like there should be a Filter filters inside of the Filters class but I can't wrap my head around the conflicting "filters" that Jackson wants/needs to return.

Comment: I changed "List<Filter> filters" to "List<Object> filters" and my unit test passes. I printed the class name of the elements in filters.getFields() and they all say java.util.LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430715/casting-linkedhashmap-to-complex-object solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Filter class is not correct. It should extend Filters. 
After correcting your unit test (json is incorrect) it can load your json into a Filters Object.

```
public class Filter extends Filters {
    private String field;
    private String operator;
    private String value;
    // accessors/mutators/toString
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I merged Filter and Filters into one class and then added @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) to the class to remove all of the fields that don't apply.

Comment: I've tried several times to add my final solution but I keep getting an error saying "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." even though it's formatted correctly in the preview.