# Deserializing Generic Types with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, gson

I have some problems with implementation of Json Deserialization in my Android application (with Gson library)

I've made class like this

```
public class MyJson<T>{
    public List<T> posts;
}
```

And Deserialization call is:

```
public class JsonDownloader<T> extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyJson<T>> {
...
protected MyJson<T> doInBackground(Void... params) {
  ...
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<MyJson<T>>() {}.getType();
    result = gson.create().fromJson(reader, collectionType);
  ...
  }
}
```

Problem is that result.posts list after call holds one Array of LinkedTreeMap Objects(with correct values so problem is Deserialization) instead of MyJson Objects. When I use MyObject instead of T everything is running fine and MyObject is correct.

So is there any way to implement deserialization call without creating custom deserializer?

Comment: I'm curious to know why did you use a `GsonBuilder` to get a `Gson` instance, instead of doing `new Gson.fromJson` directly. What kind of benefit might be obtained from this builder?

Comment: @SebasSBM `GsonBuilder` has a `registerTypeAdapter` method is required for implementing custom deserializers for types.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to specify the type of `T` at the time of deserialization. How would your `List` of `posts` get created if `Gson` didn't know what `Type` to instantiate? It can't stay `T` forever. So, you would provide the type `T` as a `Class` parameter.

Now assuming, the type of `posts` was `String` you would deserialize `MyJson<String>` as (I've also added a `String json` parameter for simplicity; you would read from your `reader` as before):

```
doInBackground(String.class, "{posts: [\"article 1\", \"article 2\"]}");

protected MyJson<T> doInBackground(Class<T> type, String json, Void... params) {

    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<MyJson<T>>(){}.getType();

    MyJson<T> myJson = gson.create().fromJson(json, collectionType);

    System.out.println(myJson.getPosts()); // ["article 1", "article 2"]
    return myJson;
}
```

Similarly, to deserialize a `MyJson` of `Boolean` objects

```
doInBackground(Boolean.class, "{posts: [true, false]}");

protected MyJson<T> doInBackground(Class<T> type, String json, Void... params) {

    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<MyJson<T>>(){}.getType();

    MyJson<T> myJson = gson.create().fromJson(json, collectionType);

    System.out.println(myJson.getPosts()); // [true, false]
    return myJson;
}
```

I've assumed `MyJson<T>` for my examples to be as

```
public class MyJson<T> {

    public List<T> posts;

    public List<T> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }
}
```

So, if you were looking for to deserialize a `List<MyObject>` you would invoke the method as

```
// assuming no Void parameters were required
MyJson<MyObject> myJson = doInBackground(MyObject.class);
```

Comment: and where exactly is `Class<T> type` used in your code?

Comment: @Mr.Yetti The parameter `type` isn't used directly but still specifies what type `<T>` is of everywhere else in the method code. So, when you pass the `type` as `MyObject.class`, the method works with a `TypeToken<MyJson<MyObject>>` and returns a `MyJson<MyObject>`.

Comment: No, it won't because of type erasure at runtime. Therefore, your function will always return `MyJson<Object>` no matter what type you pass as an argument.

Comment: @Mr.Yetti Type erasure is a run time thing and has nothing to do with the `type` parameter which is present here to satisfy the generic return type of the method in a statement like `MyJson<MyObject> myJson = doInBackground(...)` **at compile-time**. Remove the `type` and see what compiler error is thrown to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: What exact error do you get? The `doInBackground` function must be inside a generic-typed class, e.g. `class JsonDownloader<T>`, or your code won't compile anyway. Therefore, the `type` parameter doesn't matter. If the method is not inside a generic class, then the signature `<T> MyJson<T> doInBackground(String json, Void... params)` is sufficient to avoid explicit cast, but that still won't save you from runtime errors.

Comment: What I mean with runtime errors is: `MyJson<Integer> doInBg = doInBackground(Integer.class, "{posts:['text1','text2']}");
        double toDouble = doInBg.getPosts().iterator().next().doubleValue();
        System.out.println(toDouble);` Your `type` doesn't do anything and your code will fail.

Comment: this answer is incorrect and gson will throw a ClassCastException exception.
You need to specify the full type every time, you can't make it generic.
e.g `Type type = new TypeToken<LinkedList<SomeClass>>(){}.getType();`

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried?

```
gson.create().fromJson(reader, MyJson.class);
```

**EDIT**

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type) post it seems that you use of `Type` is correct. I believe your issue is the use of `T`. You must remember that with Java there is type-erasure. This means that at runtime all instances of `T` are replaced with `Object`. Therefore at runtime what you are passing GSON is really `MyJson<Object>`. If you tried this with a concrete class in place of `<T>` I believe it would work.

[Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: OK my solution is to send Type as parameter when creating JsonDownloader class, then everything works fine. I didn't know about Type Erasure so thanks for pointing me on it.

Answer (score 7):

So the above answer didn't work for me, after trial and error that's how my code ended:

```
public class AbstractListResponse<T> {
    private List<T> result;

    public List<T> getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }
}
```

The important part here is the method signature, including the '< T >' on the left.

```
protected <T> AbstractListResponse<T> parseAbstractResponse(String json, TypeToken type) {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .create()
            .fromJson(json, type.getType());
}
```

When calling Gson, the method receives the TypeToken of the generic object.

```
TypeToken<AbstractListResponse<MyDTO>> typeToken = new TypeToken<AbstractListResponse<MyDTO>>() {};
AbstractListResponse<MyDTO> responseBase = parseAbstractResponse(json, typeToken);
```

And finally the TypeToken can use MyDTO, or even a simple object, just MyDTO.

Comment: Excellent example. Perfect solution for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone struggling with Kotlin like I did, I've found this way to work

```
val type = object : TypeToken<MyJson<MyObject>>() { }.type
val response = gson.fromJson<MyJson<MyObject>>(reader, type)
```

Note that calling a generic function requires the type arguments at the call site after the name of the function (seen [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions))

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gson 2.8.0 or higher, you can use the following method `TypeToken#getParametized((Type rawType, Type... typeArguments))`

Example:

```
protected MyJson<T> doInBackground(Class<T> type, String json, Void... params) {

    GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
    Type collectionType = TypeToken.getParameterized(MyJson.class, type).getType();

    MyJson<T> myJson = gson.create().fromJson(json, collectionType);

    System.out.println(myJson.getPosts()); // [true, false]
    return myJson;
}
```

I believe this would work in your case.

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303941/1204249).

Answer (score 1):

I used the above answer to figure out more generic way in Kotlin (but you can reuse in java with minor adjustment)
I have `BaseDB<T>` which loads `Table<T>`, while Table has a `List<T>`

```
fun parse(jsonString: String): Table<T> {
    //this gets the class for the type T
    val classT: Class<*> = (javaClass
        .genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<*>
    val type = TypeToken.getParameterized(Table::class.java, classT).type
    return GsonHelper.gson.fromJson<Table<T>>(jsonString, type)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot of comments I found a solution which works for me and also does throw an error due to type erasure.

Below is a sample

```
public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> type)  {
    String json = mPref.getString(key, null);
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
}
```

**mPref** is the object SharedPref replace this with your object

And you can call the above method like this

```
get("Test", User.class);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You wrote (in your answer): _and also does throw an error due to type erasure_ So your code throws an error? So it does not solve the posted question? So are you asking another question? So this is not an answer?