# How to deserialize a json string which one of its subtype is generic

Tags: json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a class as shown below:

```
Class MyClass
{
   int a;
   String b;
   List<T> resource;
}
```

resource can be a candidate of 2 type of list of classes: Class A or Class B

How can I deserialize the json string to the MyClass type correctly? I used Gson library, are there any solutions in that library?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson