# How to deserialize JSON object from generic type in Java?

Tags: java, json, generics, mapping, gson

I am trying to map JSON response as below:

```
{
    object: {
    id: 1
    name: "my name"
    email: "username@mail.com"
    username: "username"
    password: "password"
    mobile: "##########"
    fbAccessToken: "----------"
    img: null
    }
    errorMessage: ""
    successMessage: ""
    technicalErrorMessage: ""
    error: false
  }
```

so I wrote this method:

```
private <T> ResponseEntity<T> processedRequest(HttpRequestBase requestBase, Class<T> tClass) throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(requestBase);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());

        Type type = new TypeToken<ResponseEntity<T>>() {}.getType();

        ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

        return responseEntity;
    }
```

based on `ResponseEntity` class:

```
public class ResponseEntity<T> {

private T object;
private boolean isError;
private String errorMessage;
private String successMessage;
private String technicalErrorMessage;

public ResponseEntity() {
    setSuccessMessage("");
    setError(false);
    setErrorMessage("");
    setTechnicalErrorMessage("");
}

public T getObject() {
    return object;
}

public void setObject(T object) {
    this.object = object;
}

public boolean isError() {
    return isError;
}

public void setError(boolean error) {
    this.isError = error;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public String getTechnicalErrorMessage() {
    return technicalErrorMessage;
}

public void setTechnicalErrorMessage(String technicalErrorMessage) {
    this.technicalErrorMessage = technicalErrorMessage;
}

public String getSuccessMessage() {
    return successMessage;
}

public void setSuccessMessage(String successMessage) {
    this.successMessage = successMessage;
}}
```

but I am getting result as `ResponseEntity<LinkedTreeMap>` and the object is map of (`Key->Value`) not the actual mapped object that send by the Type `ResponseEntity<T>`.

The image below is what appeared in the debugger:

[image: image from debugger]

Comment: Can you be more clear what is the problem? The  debugger seems to show the map as requested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

Comment: @joshp, thanks for your interest, the debugger show the object as TreeMap to the actual object.
For example if the generic <T> is instance of class UserDto the object of desalinized json must be object of UserDto to TreeMap (Key->Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How GSON should understand, which class it should use in place of `T` and what is the "actual mapped object that send by the Type" to fill it's fields? We have [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for generics in Java, so no way in runtime to understand what it `T`. No way, so gson just uses generic `Map<String, String>()`.

Take a look at responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson), it's the same situation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, i was wondering if their is work around to do that. or what is the best practice to do a generic Mapper from Json String to java Object in web service client ?