# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class when use Generic Type

Tags: java, android, generics, exception, casting

I make a class extend AsyncTask to parse Json use Gson, because input can be many type of class I use generic type:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> extends AsyncTask...
```

I need know class type of T to pass Gson with:

(1)

```
Class<T> clazz =
    (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)
        getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];

new Gson().fromJson(reader, clazz);
```

However, Here T can be a class that have many type so that some time I pass class:

(2)

```
public class DataMessage<T> implements Serializable{...}
```

With these class have this format I received a Exception Caused by:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`

at (1)

How do I do in this case ?

UPDATED:

```
public class DataMessage<T> implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("pagination")
    private Pagination pagination;
    @SerializedName("meta")
    private Message meta;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private T data;

    public DataMessage(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return pagination;
    }

    public void setPagination(Pagination pagination) {
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }

    public Message getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(Message meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public class Pagination {
        @SerializedName("next_max_tag_id")
        public String nextMaxTagId;
        @SerializedName("deprecation_warning")
        public String deprecationWarning;
        @SerializedName("next_max_id")
        public String nextMaxId;
        @SerializedName("next_min_id")
        public String nextMinId;
        @SerializedName("min_tag_id")
        public String minTagId;
        @SerializedName("next_url")
        public String nextUrl;
    }

    public class Message {
        @SerializedName("error_type")
        public String errorType;
        @SerializedName("code")
        public int code;
        @SerializedName("error_message")
        public String error_message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Gson - deserialize list<class> object? (generic type)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554217/google-gson-deserialize-listclass-object-generic-type)

Comment: Can you please add the Json object to the question?

Comment: Hi Mr @AndreaCatania pls see I upated.

Comment: I refered to @yole link and see that output of Gson is LinkedTreeMap cannot cast to my data type

Comment: If you can paste the JSON Object

Comment: in DataMessage, T type can be any object. It is not special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrea Catania with your useful help,

Problem here is when I cast `((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];` to `Class` type, With `DataMessage<T>` type it can't cast.

But `((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]` have type is **Type** so that I don't need cast it to **Class**, I retype `clazz` variable to **Type** (not **Class**) and problem have been resolved.

Comment: glad to have helped mate

Answer (score 2):

When I need to parse JSON with specific class using Gson, I use **GsonBuilder** in this way

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
   public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        try{
           return new Date( json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong()*1000L );
        }catch( Exception e ){
            return null;
        }

   }
});

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

In your case I think that you can simply parse your JSON in this way:

```
DataMessage<YourClass> dataMessage = gson.fromJson(yourJsonObj, DataMessage.class);
```

Another thing is that you can obtain the exact Type in this way

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<DataMessage<T>>() {}.getType();
```

But probably you will get a bad Json when you deserialize this...

The best way is to use the class instead of T so Gson know exactly what has to serialie/deserialize

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<DataMessage<YourClass>>() {}.getType();
```

I found this for you [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

Comment: Problem is my DataMessage class I also use Generic Type, If I work with other class the class can be easy got by clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

Comment: Can you know before parsing the type of T?

Comment: I need get class to put "...fromJson...", because we can't use T.getClass or T.class

Comment: yes, I put type of T when call AsyncTask, Ex: new ApiResponse<DataMessage<List<User>>>(context).execute....

Comment: Yes, if I fix class in Gson.fromJson by DataMessage.class result is fine. But my class ApiResponse accept all type it ban be User or DataMessage<User> ....

Comment: Have you tried to define the possible classes of T using GsonBuilder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101653/discussion-between-andrea-catania-and-mdtuyen).

Comment: Which is the problem with this? Type collectionType = new TypeToken<DataMessage<T>>() {}.getType();

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to deserialize a list of `DataMessage<T>` [using a JsonReader](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type)).

```
public <T> T Gson::fromJson(JsonReader reader, Type typeOfT)
```

Then you have

```
..
import java.lang.reflect.Type; // make sure you add this import

class DataMessageList<T>
{
    public List<DataMessage<T>> list;

    public DataMessageList ()
    {
        list = null;
    }

    public void readJson (JsonReader reader)
    {
        Type TT = new TypeToken<ArrayList< DataMessage<T> >>(){}.getType();

        this.list = new Gson().fromJson(reader, TT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which the difference with my answer?

Comment: If you read all my answer I've written that: Type collectionType = new TypeToken<DataMessage<T>>() {}.getType();

Comment: @AndreaCatania The difference is in the import, and that my snippet is coherent.