# How to get instance of class<T> from json string in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class as below:

```
class TestJson<T>{
  public String status;
  public String message;
  public ArrayList<T> result;
}
```

and I need define a function like this:

```
 TestJson<T> toJSONClass(class<T> cls);
```

a JSON string like this:

```
{"status":"1"; "message":"OK", "result":[[1, "a"],[2, "b"],[3, "c"]]}
```

a template class like this

```
class ResultClass{
  int a;
  String b;
}
```

the way to call `toJSONClass` like this:

```
TestJosn<ResultClass> tj = toJsonClass(ResultClass.class)
```

How can I define the function to get a Instance of `TestJson<ResultClass>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson

Comment: I tried, but ResultClass can't be deserialized correctly.

Comment: @LiGa your `ResultClass` will need to have custom deserializer to produce `[1, "a"]` output. gson will expect `{"a":1, "b":"a"}`