# Deserialize a parameterized type with a parameterized member field using Gson

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization, gson

I want to use the [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to (de)serialize a parameterized type that has a parameterized member field.

The class looks like this:

```
public class Foo<T>{
    List<T> bar;
}
```

How do I go about this?

I tried using a `TypeToken` like so:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Foo<String>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson<Foo<String>>(json, type);
```

This throws an `IllegalStateException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post might help you: [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

TLDR, I tried it out for your class and you can use this code to deserialize Foo:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
String json = "{\"bar\":[\"thing1\",\"thing2\"]}";
Foo deserFoo = gson.create().fromJson(json, Foo.class);
System.out.println(deserFoo.bar);
```

It outputs [thing1, thing2]

Comment: Thanks, reading your code made me realize the error I was getting was due to a syntax error in my json test string. There was no problem with the serialization after all. :facepalm: