# How to set an ArrayList Type dynamically using the class name?

Tags: java, reflection, gson

Using the Gson library, I convert a JSON string to an ArrayList Object by following code:

```
posts = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType());
```

and I use the following code for convert a json to a class objec:

```
obj = gson.fromJson(json, Class.forName(fullClassName));
```

You see in the second code that I used reflection to specify the type of class;
but for the first code, I don't know how to specify the type of list using reflection.

What do I do?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

Comment: Thanks Luk, Worked for me The third answer, but I can't cast the ArrayList Items to original class object, that throw an exception with this message: `"com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap can not be cast to com.example.test.User"`. of course I passed `Class.forName("com.example.test.User")` as a parameter for the `Class<T> type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I understand you need to deserialize list of objects but type isn't known on compile time but you are providing it dynamically?
You probably want to use something like that for your type:

```
TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, Class.forName("foo.bar.MyDynamicType"))
```

This will create same type as

```
new TypeToken<List<MyDynamicType>>(){}.getType()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's worked correctly with this: `Object list = gson.fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, Class.forName("foo.bar.MyDynamicType")).getType());`. So, I can cast the list object to original Class object, without any problem.