# How to this JSON Parsing Android infinite data

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arraylist

The API I'm using provides a JSON output. How can I parse it on android studio? I've never seen a JSON printout like this before.

```
{
"market":   {
        "100": {
        "name": "forexample",
        "surname": "forexample2"
},
         "101": {
        "name": "forexample3",
        "surname": "forexample4"
},

.
.
.

 "999": {
        "name": "forexampleXX",
        "surname": "forexampleXX"
}
}
}
```

"101" continues to increase by 1. It's going to be too long to make individual identifications. What's the shortest way?

Comment: post complete `JSON` .

Comment: what´s strange about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: its just object inside object

Comment: Convert "market" JsonObject to JSONArray. It become easier.

Comment: "101" continues to increase by 1. It's going to be too long to make individual identifications. What's the shortest way?

Comment: Change your market object to array.

Comment: @Bill, Do you have backhand code for json response  ?

Comment: @Bill, I have updated answer now, you can get all values from your json Object.

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you get data from your desired Object

```
    JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
    json = response.getJSONObject("market");
    Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();//here you get 100,101,102 ....without accessing individually
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);//Here you get you object values
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
    }
```

[Further details read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573913/android-jsonobject-how-can-i-loop-through-a-flat-json-object-to-get-each-key-a/13573965#13573965)

*Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.*

Comment: "101" continues to increase by 1. It's going to be too long to make individual identifications. What's the shortest way?

Comment: @Bill shortest way is to change your json response and make that a json array

Comment: How should I define "101" to create a json array?

Comment: @Bill, yes one way is to  change your response into Json array else you need to follow pattern to the specific number i.e in your case it is from 100-999 but remember if your response change at any point it will crash.

Comment: @Bill you no need to define 101 in array, you can access array with position

Comment: @VivekMishra so, How will it be? can you talk briefly?

Comment: yes @VivekMishra is suggesting right, in array you don't need to access position by name while is object you are required to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your "market" JSON should be **JSONArray**. Show you can use content with index.

Change your API output. Like,

```
{
"market":   [
         {
        "name": "forexample",
        "surname": "forexample2"
         },

         {
        "name": "forexample3",
        "surname": "forexample4"
         },

.
.
.

    {
        "name": "forexampleXX",
        "surname": "forexampleXX"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't change the API output. Is there another way?

Comment: What issue you are facing for changing output ? Because this is the only efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/google/gson. 
And transform the json to something like

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Person>> map
```

This article could help for parsing this type- [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)

Person would be a class with name and surname.
First get the first level keys. -> map.keySet(), and for each new hashmap get the next level key. Something like

```
for (String key: map.keySet()) {
 HashMap < String, Person > personMap = map.get(key);
 for (String personKey: personMap() {
   Person person = map.get(personKey);
   // do what you want with the person object
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library it is very famous library
add it like this

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

then u can parse it like this

```
Market market = new Gson().fromJson( jsonString , Market.class);
```

where Market Class will be

```
public class Market {
     public HashMap<Integer ,  User > result ;
}
```

AND

```
public class User{ 
    public String name ;
    public String surname ;
}
```

---

Or u can parse it without a class like this

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String, User>>  result = gson.fromJson( jsonString , new TypeToken<HashMap<String,HashMap<String, User>>>() {
                        }.getType());
```

Hope this will help you @Bill.