# How to make the method universal using generics

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the import From JSON method universal for working with different classes. But I'm confused about these generics.

```
private <T> List<T> importFromJSON(DataItems<T> dataItems) { 
  try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
      InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)){
  Gson gson = new Gson(); 
  dataItems = gson.fromJson(streamReader, DataItems<>.class); 
  return  dataItems.getList(); 
 } 
 catch (IOException ex){ 
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
 } 
 return null; 
} 

public class DataItems<E> { 
 
    private List<E> list; 
 
    public List<E> getList() { 
        return list; 
    } 
 
    public void setList(List<E> list) { 
        this.list = list; 
    } 
} 


public class House { 
    int number; 
    String name; 
}
```

json file

```
{"list":[{"name":"01","id":1},{"name":"02","id":2}]}
```

I call this method already with a specific type

```
DataItems<House> dataItems = new DataItems<>(); 
importFromJSON(dataItems);
```

Everything is readable, as a result of executing import From JSON, I get a list of objects, but only instead of the int type, for some reason there is a Double type
And when trying to pull an object from this list

```
House house = (House) list.get(0);
```

получаю Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to House
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson

Comment: The thing is that generics in Java are there to provide extended static time type checking. At runtime, generics are erased. So if I understand your question correctly, it is not possible to do what you are trying to do with generics in Java

Comment: Instead, I recommend using the factory pattern where you can add type handlers (ie handler registers for handling of one type of message through some form of identification)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing Generic Types with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397342/deserializing-generic-types-with-gson)