# ClassCastException: RestTemplate returning List<LinkedHashMap> instead of List<MymodelClass>

Tags: java, android, spring, classcastexception, resttemplate

I'm trying to access getter methods on my MyModelClass but my code is returning `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead of `List<MyModelClass>`. This is my code.

```
List<MyModelClass> myModelClass = 
   (List<MyModelClass>) restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm,List.class);

System.out.println("Response= " +  myModelClass);
```

I tried to print the response and I got the JSON Response that I'm expecting.
but when I tried to run this code.

```
System.out.println("Response= " +  myModelClass.get(0).getMessage());
```

It will produce this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.XXX.XXX.MyModelClass
```

It is a mismatch. Can someone help me to get rid with this error? thanks.

MyModelClass

```
public class MyModelClass{
        
    /**
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;
    
    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String type;
    
    @JsonProperty("user")
    public String user;
    
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;

    //getters
```

Error for

```
MyModelClass[] myModelClass= restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm, myModelClass[].class);

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Could not read JSON: 
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

JSON Response Structure

```
    [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","parameters":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5"}},
{"key12":"value12","key22":"value22","parameters":{"key12":"value12","key22":"value22","key32":"value32","key42":"value42","key52":"value52"}}]
```

If there is any suggestion on how to map this kind of JSON Response in RestTemplate,It would help a lot. thanks

Comment: Hi Erick, have you found any solution for your problem? I have almost same problem too

Comment: This answer helped me out to solve the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453159/822436

Comment: There is some way to convert List<LinkedHashMap> to List<MyModelClass>. But why it doesn't throw any exception when restTemplate retruns List<LinkedHashMap> and assgin it to myModelClass[]? They are differnt types. Why?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

With the following method call

```
List<MyModelClass> myModelClass=(List<MyModelClass>) restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm,List.class);
```

All Jackson knows is that you want a `List`, but doesn't have any restriction on the type. By default Jackson deserializes a JSON object into a `LinkedHashMap`, so that's why you are getting the `ClassCastException`.

If your returned JSON is an array, one way to get it is to use an array

```
MyModelClass[] myModelClasses = restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm, MyModelClass[].class);
```

You can always add the elements from that array to a `List`.

I can't remember since what version, but [`RestTemplate#exchange`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.lang.Object...-) now has an overload that accepts a [`ParameterizedTypeReference`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html) argument. The `ParameterizedTypeReference` is the type token hack for suggesting a parameterized type as the target for deserialization.

You can refactor the code above to use `exchange` instead of `postForObject`, and use `ParameterizedTypeReference` to get a `List<MyModelClass>`. For example

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModelClass>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModelClass>>() {
};
ResponseEntity<List<MyModelClass>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(mvm), typeRef);
List<MyModelClass> myModelClasses = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Answer (score 2):

With the following method call , you can convert `LinkedHashMap` to `List`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new  ObjectMapper();
List<Object> list = mapper.convertValue(listResponse, new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {})
```