# Passing Hashmap<String, List<MyModelClass>> from Spring Rest Controller resulting in HashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap>>

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass HashMap < String, List< MyModelClass>> from Spring Rest Controller. From the Rest Controller the values are returned as expected. But when the client receives the returned object is resulting in HashMap < String, List< LinkedHashMap>> instead HashMap < String, List< MyModelClass>>.

Below is the call from client service method.

```
Map<String, List<MyModelClass>> map = new HashMap<String, List<MyModelClass>> ();
map = (Map<String, List<MyModelClass>>)restTemplate.getForObject(restURL + "/someMethod/"+parameter, HashMap.class);
```

What am I doing wrong here. How would I get the Map < String, List< MyModelClass>> in client service instead of Hashmap < String, List< LinkedHashMap>>. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463372/classcastexception-resttemplate-returning-listlinkedhashmap-instead-of-listm) worked for me.

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModelClass>> typeRef 
    = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyModelClass>>() {};

ResponseEntity<List<MyModelClass>> responseEntity 
    = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(mvm), typeRef);

List<MyModelClass> myModelClasses = responseEntity.getBody();
```