# How to instantiate a generic list type in cucumber for tests

Tags: java, generics, cucumber

I want to reuse an cucumber assertion that verify if a spring Page of some type contains in any order an datatype. I was able to get it working with list, but not with generic Page

My code:

```
Scenario: List all brands
    Given I have brands in database
      | id | name                          |
      | 1  | brand name for list           |
      | 2  | second brand for list         |
    When I Set GET Brand Endpoint
    When I Set First Page Params
    When I send a GET HTTP request for a page of type com.kugelbit.mercado.estoque.domain.product.Brand
    Then I receive a valid response code for page 200
    Then I receive a valid response page of type com.kugelbit.mercado.estoque.domain.product.Brand
      | id | name |
      | 1  | brand name for list |
      | 2  | second brand for list |
```

```java
@When("^I send a GET HTTP request for a page of type ([^\"]*)$")
  public void iSendAGetHTTPRequestForPageOfType(String type) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(type);
    final UriComponentsBuilder[] uriComponentsBuilder = {UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(this.apiUrl)};
    if(this.urlSearchParams != null) {
      urlSearchParams.forEach((key, value) -> {
        uriComponentsBuilder[0] = uriComponentsBuilder[0].queryParam(key, URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      });
    }

    CustomPageImpl customPage = new CustomPageImpl(List.of(aClass.newInstance()));

    String uriBuild = uriComponentsBuilder[0].toUriString();
    ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<?>> forEntity = (ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<?>>) testRestTemplate.exchange(uriBuild, HttpMethod.GET, null, customPage.getClass());
    this.responseEntityPage = forEntity;
  }
```

```java
@Then("^I receive a valid response page of type ([^\"]*)$")
  public void iReceiveAValidResponsePageOfType(String type, DataTable dataTable) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(type);
    List<?> expected = dataTable.asList(aClass);
    Object[] body = responseEntityPage.getBody().getContent().toArray();
    assertThat(body).containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expected);
  }
```

The assertion is failing with the following:

> Step failed java.lang.AssertionError:  Expecting actual:   [{"id"=1,
> "name"="brand name for list"},
> {"id"=2, "name"="second brand for list"}] to contain exactly in any order:   [Brand(id=1, name=brand name for list), Brand(id=2,
> name=second brand for list)] elements not found:   [Brand(id=1,
> name=brand name for list), Brand(id=2, name=second brand for list)]
> and elements not expected:   [{"id"=1, "name"="brand name for list"},
> {"id"=2, "name"="second brand for list"}]

Which means that the expected is a list of type Brand which is correct I do have a DataTable conversion. The actual body has the same properties but is list of type Object

I did think in two possible solutions:

1. Find a way to make the request passing the correct generic type of Page
2. Find another assertion that compares the contents of the objects in the array ignoring the type.

Note.: My `CustomPageImpl` is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54423639

Here is a project with junit test to simulate the problem of assertion in a rest template generic page: https://github.com/giovannicandido/spring-test-generic-resttemplate-question

Comment: What is the result of `body[0].getClass()`?

Comment: Is: class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: I think the trick here is to create the appropriate ParameterizedTypeReference as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463372/classcastexception-resttemplate-returning-listlinkedhashmap-instead-of-listm question is how to do that passing the type as CustomPageImpl<ConcretType> when ConcretType is a Class parameter

Comment: I edit the question with a link to a project that simulates the problem with JunitTests, if someone figures out how to make the listWithClassType test pass like the other two examples are passing then it will close this question.

Comment: So you are comparing instances of `LinkedHashMap` against instances of `Brand`. They'll never be considered equal because they're of a different type. Either convert the expected values to a `Map`, or the actual value to `Brand`.

Comment: And fundamentally, I don't think you should use Cucumber for these tests. MockMvc seems much more appropriate for what you are testing here.

Comment: Also note that testing against `Brand` is not effective. Because you use `Brand` in both the definition of the project and the expected value, the test is a bit of a tautology. So it would be better to test against the json representation.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to build the ParameterizedTypeReference using a factory, that way it is generic:

```java
public class ParameterizedTypeReferenceFactory {

  private static Map<Class<?>, ParameterizedTypeReference<? extends CustomPageImpl<? extends Object>>> parameterizedTypes = Map.of(
    Brand.class,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<Brand>>() {
    },
    ProductCategory.class,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<ProductCategory>>() {
    },
    Product.class,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<Product>>() {
    },
    Market.class,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<Market>>() {
    },
    MainStock.class,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<MainStock>>() {
    }
  );

  public static <T> ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<T>> buildCustomPageReference(Class<T> aClass) {
    if (parameterizedTypes.containsKey(aClass)) {
      return (ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<T>>) parameterizedTypes.get(aClass);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot find parametrized type for class %s", aClass));
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```java
    ParameterizedTypeReference<? extends CustomPageImpl<?>> typeRef = ParameterizedTypeReferenceFactory.buildCustomPageReference(aClass);
    String uriBuild = uriComponentsBuilder[0].toUriString();
    ResponseEntity<? extends CustomPageImpl<?>> forEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange(uriBuild, HttpMethod.GET, null, typeRef);
    this.responseEntityPage = forEntity;
```