# Jackson: How to deserialize instance field of my own class

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I'm writing RESTful web service for my android app.
I have my POJO class named ServiceResponse:

```
private int responseCode;
private String objectType;
private ArrayList<Object> data;

public int getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
    this.responseCode = responseCode;
}

public ArrayList<Object> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setArrayData(ArrayList<Object> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    if(this.data == null) this.data = new ArrayList<Object>();
    this.data.add(data);
}

public String getObjectType() {
    return objectType;
}

public void setObjectType(String objectType) {
    this.objectType = objectType;
}
```

It's parsed to JSON using Jackson, example here: http://pastebin.com/pu8792a1
There will be many classes passed using this arraylist.
My question is, how do I make it ServiceResponse object again from the JSON?

```
{
  "responseCode" : 2,
  "objectType" : "com.example.User",
  "data" : [ {
    "name" : "name",
    "password" : "pass",
    "email" : "mail@gmail.com",
    "device" : "ABC",
    "level" : 10,
    "gold" : 82,
    "delois" : 0,
    "uranium" : 0,
    "attack" : 5,
    "speed" : 5,
    "armor" : 5,
    "controllability" : 5,
    "exp" : 100,
    "hp" : 100,
    "hpMax" : 300,
    "deuter" : 21,
    "deuterMax" : 120,
    "research" : 1413360596907,
    "id" : 1
  } ]
```

I tried: (skipped try & catch)

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ServiceResponse response;
    response = mapper.readValue(output, ServiceResponse.class);

    User user =  (User) ( response.getData().get(0) );
    System.out.println(user.toString());
```

but I got ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast into com.example.User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems:

### Problem 1:

```
"data" : [ {
  "name" : "name",
  "password" : "pass"
  ...
} ]

private ArrayList<Object> data;
```

Since you define the type of the list as `Object` the parser doesn't know to map it to a `User` type, so it will map it to an array of `LinkedHashMap`. So basically you're left with `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> data`. Change all the `Object` to `User`.

### Problem 2:

```
private ArrayList<User> data;
...
public void setData(User data) {
    if (this.data == null) {
        this.data = new ArrayList<User>();
    }
    this.data.add(data);
}
```

The parser will look for [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) properties that follow JavaBean naming convention i.e. `property`/`setProperty`/`getProperty`. In your case the parser thinks the `setData` is a setter to *set* the value of the `data` field. As a *setter*, it will expect an `ArrayList<User>` and not a `User` as the argument. So better to change the name to something like `addUser(User user)`. While you're at it, you should change the name of `setArrayData` to follow the name convention also.

```
public void setData(ArrayList<User> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void addUser(User data) {
    if (this.data == null) {
        this.data = new ArrayList<User>();
    }
    this.data.add(data);
}
```

Making these few changes should get it working (tested).

---

### UPDATE: Problem 1 is actually not a problem

> I know I could make it work if I used User instead of Object, but I'd like to send different objects in data array (sometimes it would be User, other time, for example Item). Is there a way to do it? [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430715/casting-linkedhashmap-to-complex-object) They say I can use this: `POJO pojo = mapper.convertValue(singleObject, POJO.class);` To convert from `LinkedHashMap` to my object, but when I try it: User user = mapper.convertValue(response.getData().get(0), User.class); User is still null

As the OP brought to my attention, we can convert the map the parser created by using `ObjectMapper.convertValue( map , User.class);`.  Not sure why the OP is getting null, but when I tested, changing the `User` types back to `Object` type, it works fine

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("test.json");
        ServiceResponse response = mapper.readValue(is, ServiceResponse.class);
        User user = (User) (mapper.convertValue(response.getData().get(0), User.class));
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Result `test.json.User@366e2eef`

---

**UPDATE 2:**

The OP wants to use the String objectType to convert the the map by type:

```
ServiceResponse response = ...
String objectType = response.getObjectType();
Class clazz = Class.forName(objectType);      // catch exception
ArrayList user = (mapper.convertValue(response.getData(), 
            TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(
                    ArrayList.class, clazz)));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know I could make it work if I used User instead of Object, but I'd like to send different objects in data array (sometimes it would be User, other time, for example Item). 
Is there a way to do it? Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430715/casting-linkedhashmap-to-complex-object
They say I can use this:
POJO pojo = mapper.convertValue(singleObject, POJO.class);
To convert from LinkedHashMap to my object, but when I try it:
User user = mapper.convertValue(response.getData().get(0), User.class);
User is still null.

Comment: I didn't now that. But I just tried it, and it works fine for me

Comment: I changed all the `User` back to `Object` and it works fine. Not sure what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Ok it works, I must've done something wrong.
Now it looks like that: ArrayList<User> users = mapper.convertValue(response.getData(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<User>>() { });

BUT now I'd like to use ServiceResponse.objectType string (which can be something like com.example.User) to instantiate that class. I know I have to use reflection to that. Do you have any idea how to accomplish it? It would be something like: ArrayList<here get Type from String> objects = mapper.convertValue(response.getData(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<here get Type from String>>() { });

Comment: `Class c = Class.forName(response.getObjectType);` to get the class. And don't use `TypeReference`. Type erasure will not allow you do it that way. Don't quote me, but I think it's deprecated. You can use `TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, c)`

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how to do it. Could you please rewrite the line I've provided: ArrayList<User> users = mapper.convertValue(response.getData(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<User>>() { });
To use String as class name? I would be very grateful! :)

Comment: Thanks, it works! But you have accidentally put User.class instead of clazz when creating TypeFactory. Cheers!